# On Area 51 example questions, what are the criteria for classing a question as 'on-topic'?

Tags: discussion, area-51, example-questions

This question below has 16 yeses to 1 no and is classed as **on-topic**

[image: on-topic]

Whereas this question has 6 yeses to 10 nos and isn't classed as **on-topic** or **off-topic**

[image: not classes as on-topic or off-topic]

Are there certain criteria before a question gets considered on-topic or off-topic. Is it a miminum number of votes in one direction and also a certain minimum difference between the yeses and nos?

Comment: What is Area 51?

Comment: @Coronatus: No such place exists. Or you could try clicking on the tag.

Comment: @Coronatus: Where ya been, man?  http://area51.stackexchange.com

Comment: This should be tagged [faq]

Comment: @Ivo thanks for the suggestion. I reckon it is a question that quite a few people will want to ask, but I think only a moderator can tag a question as [faq] so I can't do it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be marked on-topic you need:

- At least 20 on-topic votes
- At least 4 times as many on-topic as off-topic votes

It's the reverse for off-topic.

**EDIT**

The number of votes was raised to 20 (from 10), and the details have been added to the FAQ

Comment: Should this be made more clear in the FAQ?

Comment: I agree this should be in the FAQ.  I ended up having to search meta to find the answer to what I thought was a simple question.