# How does an Area 51 proposal go from definition to commitment?

Tags: support, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many on or off topic votes does a question need to count against questions needed now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52662/how-many-on-or-off-topic-votes-does-a-question-need-to-count-against-questions-ne)

I currently have 60 followers on [my proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6922/software-engineering/8298) and it says I need 5 on-topic and 5 off-topic questions. I have 31 submitted questions - 9 have more than 5 "on-topic" votes and 5 have more than 5 "off-topic votes. How many votes do I need to have for a single question to be on-topic and off-topic?

Also, is there a way this information could get added to the Area 51 FAQ? It seems like it should be in there, along with all of the guidelines for moving between stages.

Comment: Hm. That did not turn up in my searches (or I missed it because the title is kind of awkward), but it does appear to answer my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52252/on-area-51-example-questions-what-are-the-criteria-for-classing-a-question-as-o/52281#52281), To be marked on-topic you need:

- At least 20 on-topic votes
- At least 4 times as many on-topic as off-topic votes

It's the reverse for off-topic.